# How to add special characters in a UIlabel in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, special-characters

how can I add special characters in a UILabel in objective-c? Like I have to add "" in the title of navigation bar and tabbar. when I write it as it is then it shows me a square. Any idea?

Comment: How are you encoding the input text? If you're using UTF8 this should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) contains character list with its unicode value which you have to use.For Eg.

If you want to create copyright C with encircle you have to use

```
 lblCopyRight.text=@"\u00A9 2012 Anil"
```

Above will display copyright on the label.

If the above link will not contain your symbol then the only way for you is to create an image and set the property of imageview with this.

**For your symbol use `lblRegister.text=@"\u00AE 2012"`**